# Is it possible to force a specific variable into bestglm?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

My data set has 13 variables in total, and this is the glm I have currently.

```
result2 = bestglm(training_set,IC = "AIC", family = binomial, method = "exhaustive")
```

While this works fine and gives me the best model using the AIC criterion, the model generated does not include the 1 variable (var1) that I need my model to have.

Is it possible to force var1 into the above code such that it will return the best model with v1 included in it?

Thank you.

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to want to do, but without further information about the specifics it's difficult to say. _Maybe_ you could find which variable that _is_ included in the model correlates best with `var1` and remove it from your data frame before re-running, or just note the variables used in the model produced from `bestglm` and run a standard `glm` with these variables plus `var1`. The docs don't seem to offer an easy way to insist that an arbitrary variable is kept.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could look at `result2$BestModels` and see if any of the top models includes the variable (var1) you need.  If so, run a `glm` with the variables indicated.
If none use var1, increase TopModels in your `bestglm` call from the default of 5.

There is a reference in the help("bestglm") to "force.in", but it doesn't lead anywhere, and if I try to use it warns me that the extra argument will be disregarded.

Comment: thank you very much!